# Laravel retrieve records from database using mysql view instead of the table itself

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I know this is a simple question and I tried hard to search a solution for this. Maybe someone knows or experienced this already that might help me.

I am only a beginner in using Laravel please bear with me.

So I have this `AgencyModel`, the name of my table in the database is `agency`.
And I have a MySQL `view` which is named `view_agency`, this contains the inner join of the `agency` table and other tables that has connection with it.

Model (This is the working code)

```
  protected $table = 'agency';
```

The records displays when I use the `agency` as the table name

But MySQL view table `view_agency` does not display/retrive the records from the database.

Model (This code is not working)

```
protected $table = 'view_agency';
```

I have a suspicion that the laravel eloquent might have to do with this, because $table is only being accepted and not mysql view.

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
```

Thanks...

Comment: I have done this before, and it works ..., is your view's name really `view_agency`?

Comment: can you just rename $table to $readFrom  and check

Comment: You've not said what the error is, just that there is one. If you can provide the error, we can provide a better reason for it and a solution.

Comment: @TsaiKoga yes the mysql view's name is `view_agency`

Comment: @Jason ow. ok. sorry for that. forgot to mention. the error is it's just not displaying or retrieving the records

Comment: @codeseeker so did u try to call `ViewAgency::all()`, did it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In SQL, a view is a virtual table based on the result-set of an SQL statement.

And you can get datas from view **just like table's datas**:

```sql
select * from view_agency
```

So you can use Laravel query builder or Eloquent builder to query records like table,

**Laravel will convert the query builder or Eloquent to sql, so it will works**:

```php
DB::table('view_agency')->get();
```

---

I used do this before, I created a `views/` directory inside the `models/`, and create the all views' files inside.

I think you can create that view model like this:

```php
namespace App\Models\Views;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
class ViewAgency extends Model {
}
```

However, I am following the laravel's way. I use the lowercase underscore plural form. So when I use `ViewAgency`, Laravel will find the `table` or `view`'s name which is `view_agencies`:

```php
ViewAgency::first();
```

It works fine.

And If you want to change the name, and I think there is no error with `protected $table = 'view_agency;'`, You can try this way:

```php
class ViewAgency extends Model {
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->setTable('view_agency');
    }
}
```

This will work, too